# Why can't I see the 'user agent switcher' in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

This used to be in Tools --> User Agent Switcher, but it doesn't seem to be there now. I also installed another addon and this isn't appearing in the menu either. Can I access Add-Ons from a different location in Firefox 4?

Comment: Have you installed the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the User Agent Switcher options again, you just have to turn on the Menu Bar, which is turned off by default in Firefox 4.

Firefox Button In Top Left --> Options --> Menu Bar